# Python Global Variables Callback and Definition Errors

Tags: python, reference, global-variables

I am programming the below code. When I try to use globals in each if/elif indentation, I get an error stating that the variable has been used before it was made global. If I use a global only in the first if, I get an error referring to the fact that a local variable can not be edited locally.

The below code is the furthest I have gotten to it properly working. This code does not bring any errors to light when debugged, only the callback error when run.

```
global daycountone
global daycounttwo
global y
print("Input date using numbers only")
print("Ex. Day: 13")
print("    Month: 4")
print("    Year: 2009")
dayone = input("Day ")
monthone = input("Month ")
yearone = input("Year ")
print("Input another date, still using numbers only")
print("Ex. Day: 13")
print("    Month: 4")
print("    Year: 2009")
daytwo = input("Day: ")
monthtwo = input("Month: ")
yeartwo = input("Year: ")
y = yearone
while(y>0):
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycountone = daycountone + 366
                        else:
                                daycountone = daycountone + 365                 
                else:
                        daycountone = daycountone + 365
        else:
                daycountone = daycountone + 366
        y = y-1
while(y>0):
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 366
                        else:
                                daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 365                 
                else:
                                daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 365
        else:
                daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 366
        y = y-1
if(monthone == 2):
        daycountone = daycountone + 31
elif(monthone == 3):
        daycountone = daycountone + 59
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycountone = daycountone + 1
                else:
                        daycountone = daycountone + 1           
elif(monthone == 4):
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycountone = daycountone + 1
                else:
                        daycountone = daycountone + 1   
        daycountone = daycountone + 90
elif(monthone == 5):
        daycountone = daycountone + 120
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycountone = daycountone + 1
                else:
                        daycountone = daycountone + 1
elif(monthone == 6):
        daycountone = daycountone + 151
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycountone = daycountone + 1
                else:
                        daycountone = daycountone + 1
elif(monthone == 7):
        daycountone = daycountone + 181
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycountone = daycountone + 1
                else:
                        daycountone = daycountone + 1   
elif(monthone == 8):
        daycountone = daycountone + 212
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycountone = daycountone + 1
                else:
                        daycountone = daycountone + 1   
elif(monthone == 9):
        daycountone = daycountone + 243
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycountone = daycountone + 1
                else:
                        daycountone = daycountone + 1   
elif(monthone == 10):
        daycountone = daycountone + 273
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycountone = daycountone + 1
                else:
                        daycountone = daycountone + 1   
elif(monthone == 11):
        daycountone = daycountone + 304
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycountone = daycountone + 1
                else:
                        daycountone = daycountone + 1   
elif(monthone == 12):
        daycountone = daycountone + 334
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycountone = daycountone + 1
                else:
                        daycountone = daycountone + 1
if(monthtwo == 2):
        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 31
elif(monthtwo == 3):
        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 59
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1
                else:
                        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1           
elif(monthtwo == 4):
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1
                else:
                        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1   
        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 90
elif(monthtwo == 5):
        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 120
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1
                else:
                        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1   
elif(monthtwo == 6):
        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 151
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycountone = daycountone + 1
                else:
                        daycountone = daycountone + 1
elif(monthtwo == 7):
        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 181
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1
                else:
                        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1   
elif(monthtwo == 8):
        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 212
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1
                else:
                        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1   
elif(monthtwo == 9):
        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 243
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1
                else:
                        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1   
elif(monthtwo == 10):
        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 273
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1
                else:
                        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1   
elif(monthtwo == 11):
        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 304
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1
                else:
                        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1   
elif(monthtwo == 12):
        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 334
        if(y%4 == 0):
                if(y%100 == 0):
                        if(y%400 == 0):
                                daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1
                else:
                        daycounttwo = daycounttwo + 1
daycountone = daycountone + dayone
daycounttwo = daycounttwo + daytwo
daysbetween = daycounttwo - daycountone
if(daysbetween<0):
        daysbetween = -1 * daysbetween
prnt = 'The number of days between the two dates is ' + daysbetween + 'days exactly, accounting for leap years'
print prnt
```

Comment: You have no functions. There doesn't appear to be any need to declare variables as global at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python essentially follows functional scoping: see [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

Because you have no functions, you have no need of globals. When you do need to use globals, you declare them within local scopes for the first read. For example:

```
SOME_COUNTER = 0

def some_func(some_num):
    global SOME_COUNTER
    SOME_COUNTER += some_num

some_func(3)
print SOME_COUNTER  # 3
some_func(2)        
print SOME_COUNTER  # 5

def some_other_func(some_num):
    SOME_COUNTER += some_num  # this won't work; SOME_COUNTER isn't in scope

some_other_func(3)  # blows up with an UnboundLocalError saying SOME_COUNTER was used before definition (i.e. it isn't in scope)
```

Answer (score 0):

Global variables would let you modify one of your variables inside a function, but because you aren't using any function you don't need to make anything global.

There's an easier way of doing this using the [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)